# Populate select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to populate a select dropdown when the user click in the select. I am trying this, but apparently the click handler is only activated when the user click in the options, but in my case i don't have options. Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5p7pwuqy/)

```
$('select').click(function () {
    var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(currentId);

    var total = $('.total').text();

    for (i = 0; i <= total; i++) {
        $('<option>').val(i).text(i).appendTo('#' + currentId);
    }
});
```

Comment: check this https://jsfiddle.net/5p7pwuqy/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :As you are appending options for every click and hence you are not able to see the options. You can use `.one()` to populate options only for the first click and for second time click it will show you the populated options. Also use `this`
to append options instead of getting id of select box and use it.

```
$('select').one("click",function () {
    var total = parseInt($('.total').text());

    for (i = 0; i <= total; i++) {
        $('<option>').val(i).text(i).appendTo(this);//use this to append
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5p7pwuqy/3/)**

Comment: the double click is not intuitive, at all, for a normal user. The behavior in chrome and firefox are different. Also, the total should be dynamic, so the one will not work. The selected option should update the total in span.

Comment: So once you select any option from select it will again populate the select box?

Comment: I will accept the answer. My problem is more about logic. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to populate the select on mouse over, it could save you some time and give you more accessibility. Sometimes adding options on click just prevents the select from opening when it's supposed to, which can lead to frustrating the user...